# How to properly read sentences of the type: "a and b that c"

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

There are a couple of examples of these sentences, but the main question is, whether to read this as:

- a and [b that c]
  *or*
- [a and b] that c

An example would be:

> The grass and roses that are red.

Would this mean the grass is also red, or is this sentence just poorly written?

Comment: Not written poorly, written well as a joke setup.

Comment: Sentences like that are systematically ambiguous in writing. In speech, it's easy to tell from the intonation and stress.

Comment: It would be better to provide a complete sentence. "Please take away the anemones and roses that are red." Ambiguous.

Comment: @JohnLawler It reminds me of the old riddle, which I was last asked by my uncle when I was about five.  "What's black and white and red all over?"

Comment: @JohnLawler I just don't see any possible ambiguity in **phrase**  Object A and Object B that are [adjective]. Mainly because "A and B that are C" is not a really a sentence. I think the dv's on my answer are not so fair....

Answer (score -4):

**The grass and roses** that are **red.**= A and B that [are] C.

A and B that C = that is not a sentence.

Yes, in this case, the grass and the roses are red. But is it not a full sentence.
A full sentence is: The grass and roses are red.

A and [B that (are) C] is not possible, as shown below.

**The grass and /roses that are red/. is not a grammatical construction or a full sentence.

**What would be ambiguous is this**:
***The grass and roses that are red*** **should be cut**.

*To avoid that ambiguity*, one would have to write:
**The grass and the red roses should be cut.**

So yes, the first utterance that does not have an SVP (subject verb predicate) does mean the grass is red too. Think of anime or cartoons. Why not?

Comment: Usually, I don't care about DV's but I have to say, I find these particularly annoying. Not one thing I wrote is not kosher.